# wordpress 3.2.1 database query

Tags: select, wordpress

i am trying to make a simple selection in a wordpress table (created by a plugin). the table is named `reduceri` , and has the following columns: `id`, `post`, `category`.

so, i am trying to take all the category values, when the post is equal to the current post id.

the way i am doing the query is:

```
$the_query = "
SELECT $wpdb->reduceri.category 
FROM $wpdb->reduceri
WHERE $wpdb->reduceri.post = ".$post_id."    
";

$my_reduceri = $wpdb->get_results($the_query);
```

but when i `var_dump` the `$my_reduceri` all i get is an empty `array: array(0) { }` even though there should actually be some results... any idea where i am wrong (in the query)?

thank you

Comment: the code looks simple and clean,sow as dumb at it might sound start checking the basics, like, is the table empty, does the table have entries with post =.$post_id., in these cases small things are usually the problem.

Comment: hmm... checked. but i will check again. i am afraid not to be a problem with the methods that get data from the database, in w 3.2.1 thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you declared global $wpdb; before using this query?

Comment: yes i did. also i should have declared  global $post. thank you. problem solved.